# Entity Framework navigation collections performance issue

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have a many-to-many relation in Entity Framework, in the mapping, EF allow us to specify the keys and table name. In my example below, a user can have many device logs and a device log can belong to many users.

```
HasMany(e => e.DeviceLogs)
            .WithMany(e => e.Users)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("UserDeviceLog")
                .MapLeftKey("UserId")
                .MapRightKey("LogId")
            );
```

Now, when i try to remove a device log from a user:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var user = context.Users.Find(userId);
            var deviceLog = context.DeviceLogs.Find(logId);

            user.DeviceLogs.Remove(deviceLog);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I know that I'm going to delete a relation from table "UserDeviceLog", not the device log itself.
This above code snippet works, but the problem is Entity Framework will load all device logs and then remove one record from table UserDeviceLog.

[image]

My application is blocked while execute the above logic. From the screenshot you can see, there is about **23 seconds** between the two SQL statements. For the specified user, it has about 20K records(the first SQL statement). I'm guessing it was taken by transfering these 20K records from SQL Server to my application which cause my application very slow.

While this is unnecessary, how can i avoid it? I don't want to write a plain SQL delete statement, I prefer a solution in EF way.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `ChangeRelationshipState` helper from the accepted answer of the post marked as "duplicate". e.g. if you make it public extension method, instead of `user.DeviceLogs.Remove(deviceLog);` you would use `context.ChangeRelationshipState(user, deviceLog, e => e.DeviceLogs, EntityState.Deleted);` (or the equivalent `context.ChangeRelationshipState(deviceLog, user, e => e.Users, EntityState.Deleted);`) which would delete the link w/o lazy loading the collections.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, thank you! It works for me. BTW, what about to delete all the links w/o lazy loading the collections?

Comment: The minimum is to get the list with ids from db, then disable lazy loading and do some tricks with state manager and fake "stub" entity instances. In other words, possible, but not natural and tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This will occur because by accessing `user.DeviceLogs` you will lazy-load that collection.

If UserDeviceLogs is not accessible in the DbContext as a DbSet (which it typically would not as a many-to-many joining table/entity)...

What should get you there would be:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var userDeviceLog = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
       .SelectMany(x => x.DeviceLogs.Where(l => l.LogId ==logId))
       .SingleOrDefault();

    if(userDeviceLog == null)
        return;

    context.Entry(userDeviceLog).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If a DeviceLog refers to any reference that also must be deleted you will need to handle that deletion as well. But this should unlink a user from a device log without loading all links.

Comment: But this code will delete the other entity (`DeviceLog` object), not the link.

Comment: Ah, my bad.. Your mapping has no UserDeviceLog entity, User has a collection of DeviceLog mapped through to the table. The above would work with a mapped UserDeviceLog entity, but that would raise an annoying change where to get the DeviceLog you'd need to select through the UserDeviceLog.DeviceLog.  Without that joining entity, the only way I can think of would be to issue an SQL delete against the context via `ExecuteSqlCommand`. Not pretty, but...

Comment: The way I used to remove an item from a collection can be found in every Entity Framework tutorial. I can't believe this is not a best practice but can cause big performance issue. Instead of using ExecuteSqlCommand, I would prefer to declare the joined table(UserDeviceLog) explicitly and delete the relation from DbSet<UserDeviceLog>.

Comment: If you declare the UserDeviceLog entity you will likely need to alter your User and DeviceLog entities to use that because EF might chuck a wobbler if you have a mapped entity and the join declaration to the same table. If you map that entity and use it with the User and DeviceLog relations, then my example above will work without needing to declare an additional DbSet of UserDeviceLog.